# Python check for matches in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries as the following:

```
list1 = [{'key': 'owner', 'value': 'abcd'}, {'key': 'name', 'value': 'xyz1'}]
list2 = [{'key': 'owner', 'value': 'abcd'}, {'key': 'name', 'value': 'xyz1'}, {'key': 'purpose', 'value': 'test'}]
```

What is the best pythonic way to compare these lists and return True/False if all the dictionaries given in list1 are found in list2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `all`

```
>>> all(i in list2 for i in list1)
True
```

This will short-circuit and return `False` upon finding the first element that is not contained in `list2`.